# Организация текстур, буферов и тд в WebGL

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, webgl

Я пишу свой лёгкий движок для игр на основе WebGL. Есть объекты геометрий, текстур и тд. Я хочу создавать их таким образом

```
new Geometry(...);
new Texture(...);
new Mesh(...);
```

а затем добавлять их на сцены или просто отрисовывать в произвольном месте. Но возникает вопрос: как их, в дальнейшем, передавать в WebGL? Ведь, по сути, я создаю объект, не имеющий отношения к WebGL. У меня есть вариант написать методы создания этих объектов в свою обёртку над WebGL контекстом и создавать их так:

```
context.createGeometry(...);
context.createTexture(...);
context.createMesh(...);
```

В них уже будут обращения типа gl.TexImage2D(...) и тд, но это некрасиво, хочется юзать первый вариант. Вопрос: как "регистрировать" объекты, созданные первым вариантом, в самом WebGL? Есть вариант: в каждый объект добавить его WebGL представление и, при каждом вызове отрисовки проверять, создавалось ли оно. Есть ли способ получше?

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший вариант - иерархия объектов.
Часто, тебе необходимо, чтобы объекты имели некоторое отношение между собой, например танк и его башня.
Подобное тебе может предоставить такая вещь, как трансформация.

Таким образом, ты можешь сделать корневой контейнер и в него добавлять в качестве дочерних все свои классы, а при отрисовке проходить по всем и отрисовывать.

Так же для упрощения их можно добавлять в некоторый список (в данном случае рекомендую связанный список), в случае указания как дочернего в другой.